# No Member Found when use cmake construct proto

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I wish to use proto and managed by cmake.

Suppose the files are as follow

```
.
├── app1
│   ├── app1.cpp
│   └── app1.proto
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── common
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── bar.proto
│   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── foo
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── foo.proto
└── README.md
```

If I wanna just generate some cpp files, I can just use command

```
$ protoc --cpp_out=build common/bar/bar.proto
$ protoc --cpp_out=build common/foo/foo.proto
```

and the desired files can be generated.

However, if I use CMake, it will report an error as follow :

```
[ 14%] Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on foo.proto
Scanning dependencies of target FooLib
[ 28%] Building CXX object common/foo/CMakeFiles/FooLib.dir/foo.pb.cc.o
Linking CXX static library libFooLib.a
[ 28%] Built target FooLib
[ 42%] Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on bar.proto
Scanning dependencies of target BarLib
[ 57%] Building CXX object common/bar/CMakeFiles/BarLib.dir/bar.pb.cc.o
/Users/yu/Workspace/res/proto/project/build/common/bar/bar.pb.cc:79:5: error: no member named 'protobuf_AddDesc_common_2ffoo_2ffoo_2eproto' in the global namespace
  ::protobuf_AddDesc_common_2ffoo_2ffoo_2eproto();
  ~~^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [common/bar/CMakeFiles/BarLib.dir/bar.pb.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [common/bar/CMakeFiles/BarLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with cmake, so I could be missing something, but it appears to me that cmake's `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` is broken in the case where your proto files span multiple directories.

When `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` is placed in `common/foo/CMakeLists.txt`, cmake executes the following command to generate `foo.pb.*`:

```
cd /home/kenton/test/cmake-proto/common/foo &&
    /usr/bin/protoc --cpp_out /<project-dir>/common/foo \
        -I /<project-dir>/common/foo -I /<project-dir> \
        /<project-dir>/common/foo/foo.proto
```

When `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` is placed in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, cmake executes the following command to generate `foo.pb.*`:

```
/usr/bin/protoc --cpp_out /<project-dir> \
    -I /<project-dir>/common/foo -I /<project-dir> \
    /<project-dir>/common/foo/foo.proto
```

Both of these are wrong. Specifically, the flag `-I /<project-dir>/common/foo` should not be there. `-I` should *only* be used to specify the *root* of the source tree. Only `-I /<project-dir>` is correct. Again, this appears to be a bug in cmake, since AFAICT there is no documented way to make it do the right thing.

This is confusing the Protobuf compiler because it uses the file's path relative to the root directory to decide its canonical name. In your case, `foo.proto`'s canonical name should be `common/foo/foo.proto`, because this is the name that all other files use to import it. The symbol `protobuf_AddDesc_common_2ffoo_2ffoo_2eproto` is constructed from this canonical name (you can see the canonical name is encoded in it, using `_xx` as escapes for `/` and `.` characters). Unfortunately, because cmake is passing `-I /<project-dir>/common/foo` to `protoc`, the protobuf compiler concludes that `foo.proto`'s canonical name is simply `foo.proto`, with no prefix (because it thinks that `/<project-dir>/common/foo` is the source root directory, due to the incorrect `-I` flag). This causes problems when other files import `foo.proto`, because in those other files the protocol compiler believes that the canonical name is `common/foo/foo.proto`. So, it generates mismatching code.

[Here is the documentation for FindProtobuf.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindProtobuf.html) It does not contain any discussion of this issue, which makes me suspect that the authors are not aware that it is broken. However, this would seem very surprising since cmake is widely-used and this code is years old. Perhaps the documentation is simply incomplete? I would suggest filing a bug.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explaination, I also confuse about the path. May I know how do you handle the case one .proto need to import aother one? I think it is very necessary for my work.

Comment: @YuJing Me personally? Well, I don't use cmake. Mostly I have used had-written Makefile rules (you can examine protobuf's own Makefiles for an example) or [my own custom build system](https://github.com/sandstorm-io/ekam) (probably not what you want). Once [Bazel](http://bazel.io) (Google's open sourcing of their internal build system) adds `proto_library` support ([see this issue](https://github.com/google/bazel/issues/52)), it might be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help via CMake's mailing list, I got some point.

We may prepare a follow code as workaround.

```
  if(DEFINED PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS)
    foreach(DIR ${PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS})
      get_filename_component(ABS_PATH ${DIR} ABSOLUTE)
      list(FIND _protobuf_include_path ${ABS_PATH} _contains_already)
      if(${_contains_already} EQUAL -1)
          list(APPEND _protobuf_include_path -I ${ABS_PATH})
      endif()
    endforeach()
  endif()
```

`LIST(APPEND PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS "SOME_PATHS")` can add more data after -I flag.