# Building tensorflow serving client with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, tensorflow-serving

I searched for the best way to do this, but I was unable to find a clear answer.

Was anyone able to build a tensorflow-serving client using cmake?

I am having difficulties with generating CPP files from proto, since they are needed for prediction service. Those proto files also include proto files from tensorflow.

so far I have come up with this:

```
project(serving C CXX)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

file(GLOB_RECURSE proto_files RELATIVE ${serving_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/
    "${serving_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/*.proto")

set(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP_APPEND_PATH OFF)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${proto_files})

add_library(tf_protos ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
target_link_libraries(tf_protos PUBLIC ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Cmake builds successfully but the make command gives me an error:

```
No rule to make target '../tensorflow/tools/proto_text/test.proto', needed by 'tensorflow/tools/proto_text/test.pb.cc'.  Stop.
```

To overcome the problem of `.proto` includes not being found I used command

```
set(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP_APPEND_PATH OFF)
```

which was explained here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/eow2fNDUHvc

My current folder structure is

```
serving/
    CmakeLists.txt
    tensorflow/
    tensorflow_serving/
        apis/
```

Folder `apis` contains `.proto` files that are needed in the client implementation and they include `.proto` files from the folder `tensorflow`.

Is this even the right way to go?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work in the layout you have where the CMakeLists.txt file is placed in the same level as the `serving` repository [here](https://github.com/wardsng/serving/commit/a19d11b82b22a735e1af3539c8fda7fd4e17863b). You'll need to install Tensorflow too though (using [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc)).

**However**, you probably don't want to muck with a fork of the official `tensorflow/serving` repository so I went a step further and moved the CMakeLists.txt out so you can just submodule the official repository. I made an example [here](https://github.com/wardsng/inception_cmake)

The gist is that the protobuf CMake submodule expects proto files to be laid out in the [same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343018/cmake-and-findprotobuf) from which it's called. I made some modifications to the submodules to let us call it from a level above `serving` and to ensure it invokes the compiler with the include paths in the right order to support the nested structure of the proto files in `serving/tensorflow_serving/apis/*` (and placing it accordingly in the specified build directory)

Hopefully someone else with better knowhow can make this better!

Comment: I gave up. What I was able to find is, that CMake command (GENERATE_CPP) only generates the .pb files in its build tree.
What I did is copy all the needed proto files to a seperate folder (keeping the directory structure) and generated the .pb files explicitly by calling the protoc shell command. And then built a seperate prrotobuf library with cmake.

Comment: I used [this](https://github.com/philosophus/tf-serving-demo)  as a reference. Explained in more detail [here](http://fdahms.com/2017/03/05/tensorflow-serving-jvm-client/) by Florian Dahms

Answer (score 0):

These worked for me.

https://github.com/wardsng/inception_cmake

https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc

You can choose a private install directory instead of the default, e.g. /usr/local/...

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX= ..